# Reading dot data in csv file using OleDB

Tags: c#, csv, oledb

I'm using `OleDB` for reading `csv` file and loading it to a database table. But the data is loaded incorrectly. 
In file `csv` the data is 12.34.56.78 but after reading the data becomes 12.345678. The last two dots disappear. How can I read it and load correctly?

Comment: Is "12.34.56.78" a string? It seems it's reading that column as number (with a culture where "." is decimal separator).

Comment: I don't know the format from csv file. But i thought that when i read the data table seen it as a string so it change the format of the data. How can i specify the format of these data? @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: You can add schema to your datatable before you load data into it.

Comment: can u guide me some way? @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: Why don't you show the code that you use to read that data?

Comment: You may start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx